# ImportError: cannot import name 'CeilTimeout' from 'aiohttp.helpers'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, twint

I am getting an error while importing twint.
I have tried a virtual environment too.

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12356/3064374937.py
> in 
> ----> 1 import twint
>
> D:\NLP\twint\twint_*init*_.py in 
> 12 from .config import Config
> 13 from .**version** import **version**
> ---> 14 from . import run
> 15
> 16 _levels = {
>
> D:\NLP\twint\twint\run.py in 
> 2 from asyncio import get_event_loop, TimeoutError, ensure_future, new_event_loop, set_event_loop
> 3
> ----> 4 from . import datelock, feed, get, output, verbose, storage
> 5 from .token import TokenExpiryException
> 6 from . import token
>
> D:\NLP\twint\twint\get.py in 
> 10 import random
> 11 from json import loads, dumps
> ---> 12 from aiohttp_socks import ProxyConnector, ProxyType
> 13 from urllib.parse import quote
> 14
>
> c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp_socks_*init*_.py
> in 
> 3
> 4 from .proxy import SocksVer, ProxyType
> ----> 5 from .connector import (
> 6     SocksConnector, ProxyConnector,
> 7     ChainProxyConnector, ProxyInfo
>
> c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp_socks\connector.py
> in 
> 6 from aiohttp import TCPConnector
> 7 from aiohttp.abc import AbstractResolver
> ----> 8 from aiohttp.helpers import CeilTimeout  # noqa
> 9
> 10 from .proxy import (ProxyType, SocksVer, ChainProxy,
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'CeilTimeout' from 'aiohttp.helpers'
> (c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py)

Answer (score 5):

Edit requeriments.txt. 1st Line, instead `aiohttp` replace with `aiohttp==3.7.0`

See this: https://github.com/twintproject/twint/issues/1297
Maybe can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error I switched building my notebook from localhost to kaggle, fell free to use Google Collab.
Best of luck,

Answer (score 1):

you can just ra`!pip install aiohttp==3.7.0` or go with @p4W3k answer as well, you have an outdate version or not a stable one

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
aiohttp==3.7.0
```

then intalled aiohttp with

```
pip install aiohttp==3.7.0
```

and it worked